# Javascript to Call a Html Page

Tags: javascript, html, message, messagebox

So I been playing around... With POPUP Windows. It works fine but issue is the window box.  What I need help with is a simple message that appears after my score board updates the score? For example: You Scored!!!! and is it possible to pass a html page instead of a message.

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: what about a hidden div? And after you scored, show it and load your html page into this div. jQuery could look like this $("#myDiv").show.load("path/to/html.html");

Comment: How about just call an image to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the document in your new window. With that, you can write HTML in your `win` variable like that:

```
var win = window.open("", "Score", "width=200, height=100");
win.document.write("<h1>Your score is xxx </h1>");
```

Comment: Ya I have tried that and it works. But not a window more like a pop msg that has a timeout feature that appears in the middle of the page. OR Call a Image instead of a window is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, figured it out using Swatto and adding some functionality to it.